# What is $g$ in Guillemin and Pollack's Differential Topology?

Tags: differential-topology

Is it canonical immersion when it appears on Page 15, and cannonical submersion on Page 20? I never really see where it is defined, except for Page 15:

"Define $G$ s that $g = G \circ$ (canonical immersion)" - which does not really defined $g$ neither.

In both case, is $g$ an open map?

Thank you~

Comment: $g$ is defined in the diagram on the same page; it's a "local/coordinate representation" of $g$ around $x$. The sentence you quote does not define $G$; rather, it's a consequence of the definition $G(x, z) = g(x) + (0, z)$. The composition sends $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$ to $G(x, 0)$, which is just $g(x)$.

Comment: Giving a page number only helps if you tells us which book it's from(!)

Comment: Thanks @TTS, you mean "local/coordinate representation" of *$f$?*

Comment: @FlybyNight there there...

Comment: @WishingFish Yes. Can't edit it now, unfortunately. Also, $g$ is probably not open: the point of the theorem is that you can change coordinates to get a coordinate representation $x \mapsto (x, 0)$ and this isn't an open map if the dimensions aren't the same. [The image is much too "thin".]

Comment: No problem @TTS, I got it. :-B "By the denition of $g$, it also maps open sets to open sets": http://math.stanford.edu/~lhhuang/147/147_hw2.pdf. That's why I ask "the denition of g" and "its openness".. :-P

Comment: @WishingFish Submersions are different! Projection maps are open.

Comment: How about canonical submersion @TTS? Are they open..?

Comment: @TTS, locally, canonical submersion is just projection, right?

Comment: Yes, it seems like you've got the right idea. You could prove it directly in this case with balls, if you like.